# Как склеить 2 или несколько элементов воедино html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. Есть вот такая картинка. Сейчас она размещена как цельная на сайт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В силу того, что нужно заняться SEO оптимизацией было решено картинку разбить на квадратики, а текст стереть с картинки и писать отдельным тегом

. Т.е. текст на картинке должен восприниматься как текст, а не как картинка.

Сейчас, когда она стоит одним изображением у нее есть класс img-responsive, что помогает масштабировать ее для разных экранов. Так вот хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то разбить эту пикчу на несколько и к каждой части приклеить текст и все части соединить воедино. Все для того, чтобы при масштабировании текст и отдельные блоки картинки не сдвигались куда им захочется.

```
<div class="container-fluid intro_block">
    <div class="container why_ask">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <p class="small_ask">
                ПОЧЕМУ <br>ВЫБИРАЮТ<br>ЭВАКУАТОР
                <h1 class="big_ask" style = "float: left;">У НАС</h1>
                <strong class = "intro_block_ask">?</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="images/choice.png" class = "img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так выглядит сейчас.
А нужно как-то так:

```
<div class="container-fluid intro_block">
    <div class="container why_ask">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <p class="small_ask">
                ПОЧЕМУ <br>ВЫБИРАЮТ<br>ЭВАКУАТОР
                <h1 class="big_ask" style = "float: left;">У НАС</h1>
                <strong class = "intro_block_ask">?</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="images/choice.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
            <img src="images/choice2.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
            <img src="images/choice3.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
            <img src="images/choice4.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
            <img src="images/choice5.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
            <img src="images/choice6.png" class = "img-responsive" alt=""><label for="">some text</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Или прошу накидать идей, что еще можно сделать

спасибо

Answer (score 1):

я бы попробывал разбить на 6 стобцов,с отрицательным марджином , что бы они залезли друг на друга , и позиционировал абсолютом картинку(или bg простыми процентами)(ромб) по высоте, что бы они не залазили друг на друга , а уже внутри ромба позиционировал текст просто посредине, или в случае бг так же позиционировал текст ка тот же бг

Comment: Извините, а можно кусками кода. А то как-то несколько раз прочитал, в голову не лезет представление как это будет

Comment: есть 6 картинок ,
Попробовал бы:
   Разбить на 6 столбцов , необязательно использовать бутстрап , и начиная со второго дать отрицательный марджин в лево на половину ширины каждого столбца , что бы они залезли друг на друга , а там уже либо позиционируешь картинку абсолютом и тес так же , либо картинку на бг столбца и позиционируешь только текст , это уже на выбор... прошу прощение , набросать код , нет возможности